# Does CiviDiscount leave a SmartGroup-searchable marker on membership or contact record?

Tags: cividiscount

I note that a [similar question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/21497/2744) was asked several years ago here and the answer then was that it did not. I am wondering if the situation has changed since then.

Our case is that we would like to offer a fixed discount to members electing to go paperless for our publications. Obviously we would need to do SmartGroup searches that excluded those members to send to the mailing house. Does CiviDiscount provide any searchable marker to indicate if a discount is currently in force?

Our fall-back would be to create two versions of each class of membership, but that seemed like a somewhat inelegant solution if CiviDiscount could do the job.

Comment: can you add a link to the 'similar question'.

Comment: good question. i can't spot anything. contacts have the 'code redeemed' tab but no way to search on this. afaik no Activity is created. CiviRules can't be triggered by a discount afaik (but might be one way to 'catch' such info)

Comment: Here's the previous question:   https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/21497/2744

Comment: if you don't have a whole lot of Memb types could you just set up a Smart Group based on the amount they actually pay?

Comment: I had considered price-based Smart Groups but we do have a fair number of membership types and we are raising the price, so we need the old prices and the new prices for most of the year. Gets messy.

Comment: i think the idea of being able to search for any contribution that involved a Discount seems entirely sensible but clearly wasn't on the developers list. am sure someone can add it if there are available funds to do so. it may not be hard.